# Do I need to heapify after initializing a heap in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, heap, min-heap

When a heap is created to dynamically track a min value, after initialising an empty heap, do I actually need to call `heapq.heapify(heap)`? Or rather `hq.heappop()` and `hp.heappush()` will automatically do the job.. Thanks for the help!

```
import heapq as hp
heap = []
hp.heapify(heap) # is this line redundant?
for val in range(1, 100):
    hp.heappush(heap, val)
    print(heap[0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, in your case it's redundant. From the official doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

> **heapq.heappush(heap, item)**
>
> Push the value item onto the heap, maintaining the heap invariant.
>
> **heapq.heapify(x)**
>
> Transform list x into a heap, in-place, in linear time.

As you can see from the description of the `heapify` method, it's used for conversion of an existing list to a heap structure.

However, if you would like to keep the heap property of your data structure when adding new elements, then `heappush` is a way to go.

```
import heapq as hp
heap = []
for val in range(1, 100):
    hp.heappush(heap, val)
    print(heap[0])
```

However, if you would like to convert an existing array / list to a heap, then use the `heapify` method:

```
import heapq as hp
heap = []
for val in range(1, 100):
    heap.append(val)
hp.heapify(heap)
print(heap[0])
```